# Import sql files using xargs

Tags: mysql, xargs, input

I have a number of sql files to import. For a single file I use the following command:

`mysql -u root -p dbname < db.sql`

Is it possible to use xargs to bulk import all files? something like:
`ls *.sql | xargs ....`

I know that mysqlimport is the solution but I want to know if it's possible with xargs or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs` is suitable to transform input into command line parameters. But as `mysql` not accepts SQL script file name parameter, `xargs` is not handy in this case.

This is a useful use of `cat`:

```
cat *.sql | mysql -u root -p dbname
```

Anyway, your attempt to use `ls` in that way leads to the famous [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) article.

Comment: Con **cat** enation, who knew!

Comment: With a large number of files, I've run into a limit on how many CAT can process with the command you provided.  When running this in a directory with over 30k files I get the error "Argument list too long". I believe this is caused by the ARG_MAX variable that is set when the kernel is built.  In this case, I ended up using a find command similar to the one @Tom posted.

Comment: @Cloudkiller, indeed, in such case you need an alternative that doesn't build up one huge command before executing it. Using only the shell you can do it with `for file in *.sql; do cat "$file"; done | mysql -u root -p dbname`.

Answer (score 3):

If your sql files are independent of eachother it may be faster to import them in parallel:

```
parallel -j10 sql mysql://root:passwd@/dbname '<' {} ::: *.sql
```

Watch the intro video to GNU Parallel to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 1):

This command will load all sql files in the current folder, doing 8 in parallel and remove each file if it loads successfully:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sql" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P8 sh -c 'cat $0 | mysql -A -u<redacted> -p<redacted> -h<redacted> dbname && rm $0'
```

(I don't claim this is the best way to load sql files, but it does satisfy the question of using `xargs` to bulk import files)